# Remove extension from file name with help of stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Currently I have some code which is returning me fileName with extension and to do that I am using java 8 stream api. But I would like to as well trim the String in the same Stream.

```
return Files.walk(Paths.get(qPath))
                      .filter(extension -> extension.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                      .map(Path::getFileName)
                      .findFirst()
                      .map(Path::toString)
                      .get();
```

Any idea how to remove .txt from String in the stream?

Comment: nothing to do with streams. simply a `replace` or `substring` is needed

Comment: qPath.replace(".txt"," ");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wasting resources by converting the path to a string multiple times. When the intended end result is a string anyway, you can map to a string right as the first step, so you don’t need to repeat it.

```
return Files.walk(Paths.get(qPath))
    .map(p -> p.getFileName().toString())
    .filter(name -> name.endsWith(".txt"))
    .map(name -> name.substring(0, name.length()-".txt".length()))
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

Note that it doesn’t matter whether you place the last `.map(…)` step before the `findFirst()`, i.e. apply it to the Stream, or after it, applying it to the `Optional`. Due to the lazy nature of the Stream, it will still only applied to the first matching element here. But I prefer keeping the `.endsWith(".txt")` test and the subsequent `.substring(0, name.length()-".txt".length())` as close together as possible, to make the relationship between these two steps more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

To remove Just the extension if you want to use stream then it is not worth.
Use something like below, but again it has some disadvantages like `dd.txt.txt` will fetch `dd.txt`.

```
String trimmedString = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: It is worth to use stream. It easier to read stream compered to stream and some kind of one liner code. Plus you are not losing any resources to doing this kind of operation on stream or on string.

Comment: I said` to just remove` it is not worth, stream in maximum cases have an edge over conventional methods.

Comment: You are right. But as you see. I was already using stream and returning value from this. So this comment does not apply to my current code. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional map to remove the file extension -

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(""))
        .filter(extension -> extension.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
        .map(Path::getFileName)
        .findFirst()
        .map(Path::toString)
        .map(fileNameStr -> fileNameStr.substring(0, fileNameStr.lastIndexOf('.'))
        .get();
```

Or modify the current map to do so -

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(""))
        .filter(extension -> extension.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
        .map(Path::getFileName)
        .findFirst()
        .map(path -> path.getFileName().toString().substring(0, path.getFileName().toString().lastIndexOf('.')))
        .get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use :

```
String fileName = Files.walk(Paths.get(PATH))
                       .filter(extension -> extension.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                       .map(Path::getFileName)
                       .findFirst().map(Path::toString).get().replace(".txt", "");
```

Suppose the file isn't present and to avoid a *NoSuchElementException* use :

```
Optional<Path> findFirstFile = Files.walk(Paths.get(PATH))
        .filter(extension -> extension.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
        .map(Path::getFileName).findFirst();

if (findFirstFile.isPresent()) {
    String fileName = findFirstFile.get().toString().replace(".txt", "");
}
```

Comment: What if there’s another occurrence of `.txt` in the name? And why waste time searching the string for `.txt` (from the beginning) when you already know that it is at the end?